# Disable Terminal Window in Linux

Tags: install4j

Every time I start the installer under Linux, a terminal window opens with the message "Starting Installer ..."
Where is the option to disable this terminal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer is a shell script. The desktop environment opens a terminal if you execute a shell script. In some desktop environments you can disable this on a per-executable basis.

In any case, this is a manual process that cannot be configured in install4j.